# Round Robin like SQL table for tracking recent activity

Tags: sql

We need to track user activity in different time periods like 24 hours, 7 days etc.  We don't anticipate a very large number of different periods but the numbers of users will be very large, probably in the millions.  Nightly cronjob to summarize the stats for each user doesn't sound reasonable.  I know in the past I've tracked network usage like this with RRD tables but those were just BerkeleyDB's and had to be one file per statistic which wouldn't work, but that idea seems like what I'm after.  Is there a pattern/best practice that I'm overlooking?

Comment: What kind of user activity?  Web page visits on a Unix system running Apache?  Is the logging in SQL, and if so, can you post the(relevant part of the) database schema?

Comment: Why doesn't a cronjob sound reasonable? It doesn't have to be nightly it can be every 6 hours or so...

Comment: Actions would include log ins, or clicking links that would be tracked through php in an SQL table.  Regarding cron, my thinking is that if we have 1 million users and have to calculate each one against that action table, even with a date index its going to be mighty slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which architecture you want to use and which hardware you can afford.

For massive data analysis I would go for a Cluster-based framework like Hadoop: and build map/reduce functions which will treat your data.

see http://hadoop.apache.org/.

User activities can be stored in dailiy files to be uploaded to the Hadoop cluster and then processed.

Such solutions can provide you with the necessary scalability with commodity only hardware required.